# Chef Configuration support needed

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I just started looking into Chef and do not have much idea how it works.
Hence my question starts ,

1. I saw in tutorial about Chef DK, Chef Client and Chef Server. My Use case is I need some tool that can automate my configuration or replicate my configuration in different server maybe SIT, UAT or PROD by just changing in some local script. For that do i need Chef Server or I can do it only Chef DK.
2. Moreover, in Chef official site, Chef Server download is not provided for Windows Server but in their tutorial they are providing the Chef Server in Windows Server cloud..
3. Is it easier to learn and implement Chef rather than Puppet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please only one question per thread. Further, 3. is opinion-based and thus does not fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that as Stephen said, multiple questions are kind of bad form:

1. Chef Server generally acts as the central distribution and management point for configuration data, but you never technically need it. There are other workflows involving manually copying around cookbook/node data or using tools like `knife-solo`. The workflows you'll find documented in the official pages are all based on Chef Server though, so if you want to look at other options I would still learn the basic workflow first and then go from there.
2. Chef Server is not available on Windows as several of the underlying services are Linux-only. Chef Server is available on Microsoft's Azure Cloud, but on Linux instances (Azure supports many OSes).
3. Again, as Stephen said this is a matter of opinion. Try all four major tools (Chef, Ansible, Puppet, and Salt) and see which you prefer.

Comment: Thanks coderanger..yeah i am going thru the tutorial.what i am not understanding is if i am running multiple instances of tomcat in my workstation ..how can i restrict my recipe to start one instance and not all . moreover i am also confused if i want to start tomcat on another workstation how can i  make the connection to another machine and modify its services..

Comment: For what services Chef changes, you have to tell it. Presumably each of the instances has their own config files and whatnot, Chef only does what you tell it. re: remote machines, Chef is a local agent. You generally would connect via SSH and run the `chef-client` command or let it run on timer in the background (every 15m or similar).